# Finding a value three times higher than another value in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with two columns. I want to extract values that are at least three times higher in column one compared to column two.

Example dataset:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="column1 column2

1        9       3

2        5       3

3        12      2

4        2       6
")
```

Output should be:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="column1 column2

1        9       3

2        12      2

")
```

i am very new to R. Any idea what code i can use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` from `base R` by creating a logical expression from column1 and column2

```
subset(df1, column1 >= (3 * column2))
```

-output

```
#   column1 column2
#1       9       3
#3      12       2
```

---

Or with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(column1 >=  (3 * column2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c(9L, 5L, 12L, 2L), column2 = c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using base R:

```
with(df, df[column1 >= 3*column2,])
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  column1 column2
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1       9       3
2      12       2

df[df$column1 >= 3*df$column2, ]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  column1 column2
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1       9       3
2      12       2
```